# How do I pass a range of numbers (eg: 100 to 200) as command line argument in Perl?

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments

I have a Perl program that takes command line arguments.. I want to pass numbers from 100 to 200 as one argument. As it is difficult to give all the numbers between 100 and 200, is there any option to use a range operator in command line argument ?

```
./my_program --target 100..200
```

Comment: Either you rewrite the parts of the Perl program to accept ranges: `@ARGV = map   { /^(\d+)\.\.(\d+)$/ ? $1..$2 : $_ } @ARGV`, or you invoke it from (say) `bash` using the `seq` command: `./my_program --target 100..200`

Comment: ... whoops - the command line invocation should be `./my_program --target $(seq 100 200)`. But maybe you want to invoke the program in a loop? Please [edit] your post accordingly.

Comment: Thanks.. But no success. It is taking only the first value

Comment: Does your program actually take a list of targets on the command line?

Comment: Yea .. It worked!!!! I had to put quotes around the seq -  ./my_program --target "$(seq 100 200)".. Thanks Corion

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Getopt::Long;

my %options;
GetOptions(\%options, (
           'target=s',
       ))
    or die "$!\n";

die "option --target is missing!\n"
    unless exists $options{target};

my @list;
if (my($number) = ($options{target} =~ /^(\d+)$/)) {
    push(@list, $number);
} elsif (my($start, $end) = ($options{target} =~ /^(\d+)\.\.(\d+)$/)) {
    if ($start < $end) {
        push(@list, $start..$end);
    } else {
        push(@list, reverse($end..$start));
    }
} elsif (my($first, $others) = ($options{target} =~ /^(\d+)[\s,]((?:\d+[\s,])*\d+)$/)) {
    push(@list, $first, split(/[\s,]/, $others));
} else {
    die "invalid argument for --target option: $options{target}\n";
}

for my $target (@list) {
    print "${target}\n";
}

exit 0;
```

Example runs:

```
$ perl dummy.pl --target 1234
1234

$ perl dummy.pl --target 1,4,5,40,17,30
1
4
5
40
17
30

$ perl dummy.pl --target "1 4,5 40 17,30"
1
4
5
40
17
30

$ perl dummy.pl --target 4..10
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

$ perl dummy.pl --target 10..4
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
```

Comment: Judging from OP comment, this is not a Perl problem, but sh issue then...

Comment: Updated answer to handle all variants

Comment: Updated again to handle reversed list case too. OP: have fun :-)

Answer (score 2):

[Set::IntSpan](https://metacpan.org/pod/Set::IntSpan) handles the drudgery of parsing ranges:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Getopt::Long;
use Set::IntSpan;

GetOptions( 'target=s' => \( my $target ) );

my $set = Set::IntSpan->new( $target );

while( my $item = $set->next ) {
    say $item;
}
```

with results of:

```
% perl myprogram.pl  --target 1-10,12-15
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
12
13
14
15
```